# How to create a list of unique values, extracted from a column within a spatial polygons data frame?

Tags: r, gis, polygon, shapefile

Attempting to create a list of unique values, extracted from a column within a spatial polygons data frame object.

The `unique` function only works with vectors...

For example, if SPDF had a column name of "trees" with 5 records "birch", "birch", "aspen", "fir" and "pine". I would need a function that extracts unique values into a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it

unique(spatial_df[["trees"]])

Comment: Thanks, looks like the `unique()` function is the way to go.